# Google Glass and Google Map

Tags: android, google-glass

How can we develop a google glass application using an android sdk? Is it possible to show a map in google glass?

Answer (score 4):

Since you are just starting out with Google Glass, you may want to look at the starting examples and information in https://developers.google.com/glass/gdk .  You are able to present a map for a location by calling the Google Map URL with appropriate parameters.

Comment: You can find information on using Glass Mirror API for maps [here](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/location).